# multiple_matching_tokens_detected with MSAL and JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am building SPA with react and I run into a problem with code directly from Azure Portal - [Quickstart for Javascript](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/Quickstart/appId/30998aad-bc60-41d4-a602-7d4c14d95624/objectId/56777424-d5d8-44c3-a400-d24ec1929d10/isMSAApp/). (you can download full code there)

If I create-react-app and I use the code it works just fine and I can authenticate, get token and use it in the post request.

But If I use the SAME code in my app (which is already styled and with all the functionality I need) it gives me **Multiple authorities found in the cache. Pass authority in the API overload.|multiple_matching_tokens_detected` error when I authenticate.**

Just to clarify authentication goes through and I see I am authenticated, just this error is bugging me and I have no idea how to debug it.

```
function signIn() {

myMSALObj.loginPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (idToken) {
    //Login Success

    console.log(idToken); //note that I can get here!
    showWelcomeMessage();

    acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

}

```
function acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph() {
//Call acquireTokenSilent (iframe) to obtain a token for Microsoft Graph
myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
    callMSGraph(applicationConfig.graphEndpoint, accessToken, graphAPICallback);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error); //this is where error comes from
    // Call acquireTokenPopup (popup window) in case of acquireTokenSilent failure due to consent or interaction required ONLY
    if (error.indexOf("consent_required") !== -1 || error.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1 || error.indexOf("login_required") !== -1) {
        myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
            callMSGraph(applicationConfig.graphEndpoint, accessToken, graphAPICallback);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```

}

The main thing I don`t understand is that the same code works just fine in the fresh create-react-app project, but as I use it in an already existing project (just without authentication) it breaks with mentioned error.

**Full code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as Msal from 'msal'

export class test extends Component {

    render() {

var applicationConfig = {
    clientID: '30998aad-bc60-41d4-a602-7d4c14d95624', //This is your client ID
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/35ca21eb-2f85-4b43-b1e7-6a9f5a6c0ff6", //Default authority is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
    graphScopes: ["30998aad-bc60-41d4-a602-7d4c14d95624/user_impersonation"],
    graphEndpoint: "https://visblueiotfunctionapptest.azurewebsites.net/api/GetDeviceList"
};

var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, acquireTokenRedirectCallBack,
    {storeAuthStateInCookie: true, cacheLocation: "localStorage"});

function signIn() {

    myMSALObj.loginPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (idToken) {
        //Login Success

        console.log(idToken);
        showWelcomeMessage();

        acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function signOut() {
    myMSALObj.logout();
}

function acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph() {
    //Call acquireTokenSilent (iframe) to obtain a token for Microsoft Graph
    myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
        callMSGraph(applicationConfig.graphEndpoint, accessToken, graphAPICallback);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // Call acquireTokenPopup (popup window) in case of acquireTokenSilent failure due to consent or interaction required ONLY
        if (error.indexOf("consent_required") !== -1 || error.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1 || error.indexOf("login_required") !== -1) {
            myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                callMSGraph(applicationConfig.graphEndpoint, accessToken, graphAPICallback);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    });
}


function callMSGraph(theUrl, accessToken, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            console.log(this.response);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("POST", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    var dataJSON = JSON.stringify({ userEmail: null, FromDataUTC: "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z" })
    xmlHttp.send(dataJSON);
}

function graphAPICallback(data) {
    //Display user data on DOM
    // var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
    // divWelcome.innerHTML += " to Microsoft Graph API!!";
    // document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
}

function showWelcomeMessage() {
    console.log("You are looged: " + myMSALObj.getUser().name);
    // var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
    // divWelcome.innerHTML += 'Welcome ' + myMSALObj.getUser().name;
    // var loginbutton = document.getElementById('SignIn');
    // loginbutton.innerHTML = 'Sign Out';
    // loginbutton.setAttribute('onclick', 'signOut();');
}

// This function can be removed if you do not need to support IE
function acquireTokenRedirectAndCallMSGraph() {
    //Call acquireTokenSilent (iframe) to obtain a token for Microsoft Graph
    myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
      callMSGraph(applicationConfig.graphEndpoint, accessToken, graphAPICallback);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        //Call acquireTokenRedirect in case of acquireToken Failure
        if (error.indexOf("consent_required") !== -1 || error.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1 || error.indexOf("login_required") !== -1) {
            myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(applicationConfig.graphScopes);
        }
    });
}

function acquireTokenRedirectCallBack(errorDesc, token, error, tokenType)
{
 if(tokenType === "access_token")
 {
     callMSGraph(applicationConfig.graphEndpoint, token, graphAPICallback);
 } else {
        console.log("token type is:"+tokenType);
 }

}

// Browser check variables
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
var msie11 = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
var msedge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
var isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
var isEdge = msedge > 0;

//If you support IE, our recommendation is that you sign-in using Redirect APIs
//If you as a developer are testing using Edge InPrivate mode, please add "isEdge" to the if check
if (!isIE) {
    if (myMSALObj.getUser()) {// avoid duplicate code execution on page load in case of iframe and popup window.
        showWelcomeMessage();
        acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
    }
}
else {
    document.getElementById("SignIn").onclick = function () {
        myMSALObj.loginRedirect(applicationConfig.graphScopes);
    };

    if (myMSALObj.getUser() && !myMSALObj.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {// avoid duplicate code execution on page load in case of iframe and popup window.
        showWelcomeMessage();
        acquireTokenRedirectAndCallMSGraph();
    }
}

    return (
        <div>

        <h2>Please log in from VisBlue app</h2>
        <button id="SignIn" onClick={signIn}>Sign In</button>
        <button id="SignOut" onClick={signOut}>Sign Out</button>
        <h4 id="WelcomeMessage"></h4>

        <br/><br/>
        <pre id="json"></pre>
            </div>
    )
  }
}

export default test
```

Answer (score 3):

> it gives me Multiple authorities found in the cache. Pass authority in
>   the API overload.|multiple_matching_tokens_detected` error when I
>   authenticate

This error is caused because the auth SDK finds multiple matching tokens in cache for the input given to [acquireTokenSilent](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/docs/classes/_useragentapplication_.useragentapplication.html#acquiretokensilent).

Try adding the authority, and user if necessary:

```
  myMSALObj
    .acquireTokenSilent(
      applicationConfig.graphScopes,
      applicationConfig.authority
    )
    .then(
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to get back to it. I solve it by moving the whole project into fresh create-react-app. It looks like there was more than 1 instance of MSAL object thus more than one call/token at the same time.

Weird but solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'll answer it anyway since I had the same issue.

My workaround for this problem was to just clear the cache whenever this error happened. It worked in my case since this wan't a regularly occurring error for my use case.

In my project's configuration, the site is also set up to refresh and retry when an error like this occurs. So after clearing the cache, the site would reload and would work as expected since there would be no conflicting tokens in the cache.

```
import { AuthCache } from 'msal/lib-commonjs/cache/AuthCache';

...

const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(
  configuration,
  authenticationParameters,
  msalProviderConfig,
);

authProvider.registerErrorHandler((authError: AuthError | null) => {
  if (!authError) {
    return;
  }

  console.error('Error initializing authProvider', authError);

  // This shouldn't happen frequently. The issue I'm fixing is that when upgrading from 1.3.0
  // to 1.4.3, it seems that the new version creates and stores a new set of auth credentials.
  // This results in the "multiple_matching_tokens" error.
  if (authError.errorCode === 'multiple_matching_tokens') {
    const authCache = new AuthCache(
      configuration.auth.clientId,
      configuration.cache.cacheLocation,
      configuration.cache.storeAuthStateInCookie,
    );

    authCache.clear();

    console.log(
      'Auth cache was cleared due to incompatible access tokens existing in the cache.',
    );
  }
```